# How can I compare two equations in Mathematica?

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to compare two equations in Mathematica

```
a x + 3 == 1
2 x + b == 1
```

It should return value a = 2, b = 3.

I used this:

```
Solve [{a x + 3 == 1, 2 x + b == 1}, {a, b}]
```

and got

> ```
> {{a -> -(2/x), b -> 1 - 2 x}}
> ```

Comment: `Solve`? But making sure you write `a*x` or `a x`, else `ax` will be treated as a single variable.

Comment: @KraZug thanks for your reply. I did it with correct syntax but still i am not able to find for a and b. can you suggest any function or a way out to solve.

Comment: The result that you got indicates that the result that you want requires a specific value of `x`. `With[{x = -1}, 
  Solve[{a x + 3 == 1, 2 x + b == 1}, {a, b}, Reals]][[1]]`

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misunderstood your question.

Comment: try this `Table[Thread[
  Equal[Coefficient[a x + 3, x, i], Coefficient[2 x + b, x, i]]], {i, 
  0, 1}]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think what you're really looking for is this:

```
SolveAlways[{a x + 3 == 2 x + b}, x]
```

> {{a -> 2, b -> 3}}

You're comparing two polynomials and want them to be equal for all values of the variable `x`, but then they won't necessarily have the value `1`.

Answer (score 0):

The function `CoefficientArrays` gives the coefficients of the two polynomials, which you can then set equal and solve:

```
Solve[Thread[Equal @@ Normal@CoefficientArrays[{a x + 3 == 1, 2 x + b == 1}, x]]]
```

I don't understand why CoefficientArrays gives a nested list for the second equation but not the first though.